# Angular 6 Custom Element inside InnerHtml Keeps Reloading

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-elements

I successfully wrote an Angular 6 app which works fine. It is loading some content from a remote server, which contains some HTML-code. This code is displayed e.g. inside a DIV-element like this:

**another.component.html**

```
<div [innerHtml]="responseFromServer"></div>
```

Now I want to include custom elements, so that the server can deliver custom html content, e.g.

**Response from server:**

```
<my-custom-element><p>Some other HTML-content from the server</p></my-custom-element>
```

In order to recognize this custom element, I did:

- `add @angular/elements` in the console of my app.
- added `"@webcomponents/custom-elements": "^1.0.8"`to `package.json`
- added and declared the component `MyCustomElementComponent` in `app.module.ts` (both to `declarations` and `entryComponents`)
- wrote the `constructor` in the `AppModule` like the following:

**app.module.ts:**

```
constructor( private injector: Injector ) {
        const ii = createCustomElement( MyCustomElementComponent, { injector } );
        customElements.define( 'my-custom-element', ii );
    }


ngDoBootstrap() {}
```

**The problem**

The app is working fine, in a way. The problem is that the browser keeps reloading the app. When checking the elements in the dev tools, I can see that the `<my-custom-element>` is rendered repeatedly. The browser spinner in the tab is turning all the time. The app is responding rather slowly as it is doing something in a loop.

I think that the custom element is loading the app itself again and again. What should I change to prevent this?

### Update

Since I want the custom element to be rendered inside `innerHtml`, the response from the server passes `DomSanitizer`. It seems that the sanitizer is firing continuously and kind of blocking the app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!